# I want to get iOS push notification from my iphone to my Windows OS pc, is there any ways?

Tags: javascript, java, ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

There is an important application in my iphone and I don't want to miss any messages from this App, but the App is not available on PC (even no api for PC user), so is there any ways to get message from my iphone in my PC?

I am familiar to java and learning javascript, may be I can develop something to help myself?

Thanks for help

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Programmatic access to the notifications as they arrive is limited to the code of the responsible application. There isn't any way to write any code that iterates them, unless you wrote the application. Ask the developers to forward the notifications as SMS or Email messages.